# How do I change the clock position on panel in gnome 3.6?

Tags: gnome, upgrade

After the upgrade to 12.10 the clock on the gnome panel is now on the far right instead of the middle of the panel:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, it turned out to be the fault of the "system-monitor extension". It has a checkbox 'move clock'.

To move the clock back:

1. Right-click on the System Monitor extension on the panel, then select *Preferences*.
2. Uncheck the *Move the clock* option.
3. Restart GNOME shell: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , type <kbd>r</kbd> and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: I used the "counter"-method to move the clock to the right corner successfully! Thanks!